# how can i fix this problem with pip on osx?

Tags: python, macos

I am trying all day to reinstall pip or pip3
I always have the same problem when i try to run it:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_entry_point'
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall pip with curl and then with easy_install and now it's a big mess.

I am on the last Mac-osx release
I guess i should remove pip and pip3 completely, but how?

Comment: What does `python -c 'import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.__file__)'` emit (using the same interpreter involved in the error)?

Comment: ...waitaminute, since when did Apple ship Python 3.6 at all? How you installed it matters, since it impacts process to remove.

Comment: i installed with homebrew

Comment: For the future, much less messy if you install your libraries via the same package manager you used for the interpreter itself (personally, rather than Homebrew or MacPorts I use NixPkgs; it has an automated process for wrapping any package available on Pip as a Nix package, so there's innately 100% coverage for installing anything you might otherwise install via pip with nix instead). For the immediate issue, the question I posed in my very first comment is still pending. (Heading to lunch, so it'll be a while for any further response)

Comment: because i just didn't understand your question. but i try to guess and the feedback is: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc"